# How do I configure SPI on the Jetson Nano

Tags: nvidia-jetson-nano

The Jetson Nano has a 40 pin header but the pins are configured as GPIO. How does one convert this to SPI? After following the instructions in the [NVidia documentation](https://docs.nvidia.com/jetson/archives/r34.1/DeveloperGuide/text/HR/ConfiguringTheJetsonExpansionHeaders.html?highlight=jetson%20io#) I do not find spi* devices in /dev.

The instructions in [Jetson hacks](https://github.com/JetsonHacksNano/SPI-Playground) is out dated as well.

Answer (score 0):

The instructions in Jetson hacks is for Jetpack 4.3 - I am currently on Jetpack 4.6.

To setup SPI, follow the instructions in the [NVidia documentation](https://docs.nvidia.com/jetson/archives/r34.1/DeveloperGuide/text/HR/ConfiguringTheJetsonExpansionHeaders.html?highlight=jetson%20io#). Then run sudo modprobe spidev. Now running ls /dev/spi* will show spidev0.0 etc.